# How to integrate Swagger for existing APIs in my Core PHP project?

Tags: php, api, swagger, swagger-codegen, swagger-php

Framework like Laravel or Cake PHP its already supporting but I have my old core PHP project where I need to implement Swagger for its existing APIs. Please suggest me because its documentation is very hard and harsh to face.

Answer (score 0):

Swagger / OpenApi doesn't need support from a framework.

It's a yaml or json file specification that documents your rest api.

You'll need to know how your api works, it's not an automatic process.

I recommend to first write the yaml file manually to describe an api endpoint and view the file via swagger-ui.

Once you're a little familiar with the specification, you could consider swagger-php which is also framework agnostic. The benefit is that the documentation lives closer to the implementation which makes it more likely to get updated when the code changes.